# Poor compression of compact flash image, even after 0 fill

Tags: compression, dd, compact-flash

**Problem:** I am attempting to create an exact image of a compact flash and then compress the compact flash image for easier storage. The compact flash is not full (~1.5GB used, 32GB size). The problem is that when I compress the extracted image, it is not compressing well and I am not sure why.

I have tried multiple methods of compression and all result in no better than 50% compression ratio. I would assume that the zeros filling the ~30GB of the CF would compress very well and the resulting file would be ~1.5GB (or better).

What am I doing wrong? What am I overlooking?

**Approach**

- Zero the CF: dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
- Partition, Format, install files, data, etc (approx 1.5GB used)
- Create image of CF: dd if=/dev/sdb of=cf.img
- Compress CF (using gzip, bzip2, lzma, etc etc...)

**Notes**

- I am zeroing the CF by using a USB media reader, connected to a Windows 7 box. The USB device is attached to a virtual machine running Linux.

Comment: Did you open the image in a hex editor?

Comment: I know this is not what you say you want to do, but why not just create a `tar` or `cpio` archive of the files and then compress that?

Comment: @Scott it is much easier to be able to stick in a CF and click "burn" and have *exactly* what you need (all partitions, bootloader, etc) without additional configuration fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but not sure why this is the case.

I tried out [dban](http://www.dban.org/download). Booted the ISO as a virtual machine, and used the "wipe" (write zero) option. Single pass. Followed the same steps afterwards as previously outlined. And the compression worked a LOT better. My compressed image was under 100MB.

The only thing I can guess now is that when using dd, /dev/zero was outputting something funny, or it was not being correctly written to the compact flash.